# Disable Google Calendar Push Notification when app is an owner of the change

Tags: java, push-notification, google-calendar-api

When I create/update a Google Event from my app using java client:

```
events
.insert(originalCalendarId, googleEvent)
.setSupportsAttachments(true)
.execute()
```

I'm still getting push-notifications about event creation/update.
I don't want to get them since I'm the one who did these changes. The changes are applied on the app in a different way and additional push notifications are useless in this case.

However, I need to get new changes when they are made somewhere else(another app or Google Web UI).

Is there a way to handle this case? Maybe there is an approach to make Google know that push-notifications for specific queries aren't needed.

I also see that there is a property:

```
com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar.Events.Insert#sendNotifications
```

But, no matter what I set here, notifications are still sent.

Comment: There's no ad-hoc method specified in the [Push Notifications guide](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/push) to do this as the goal of this feature is to listen for resource changes in general. "This document describes how to use push notifications that inform your application when a resource changes."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have subscribed for a resource and you expect do not receive push notifications if your application have just done some changes. So you should use:

```
.insert(originalCalendarId, googleEvent)
.setSupportsAttachments(true)
.setSendNotifications(false)
.execute()
```

If you receive any way push notifications please check in your push notification `X-Goog-Channel-ID` with your own to be sure that is `Google` issue. I believe you have some old subscriptions that was not handled correctly and this is reason why do you receive the changes over `push notifications`.